# Retrieving and selecting binary values from Mysql with Python 3

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to select data from one table, and perform a query on another table using the returned values from the first table.

Both tables are case-sensitive, and of type utf8-bin.

When I perform my first select, I am returned a tuple of binary values:

```
query = """SELECT id FROM table1"""
results = (b'1234', b'2345', b'3456')
```

I'd then like to perform a query on table2 using the ids returned from table1:

```
query = """SELECT element FROM table2 WHERE id IN (%s) """ % results
```

Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Absolutely not, your values added with `%` are not escaped and is not guaranteed to work (not to mention the injection vulnerability).

Comment: What mysql library are you using?

Comment: Mysql.connector. I tried parameterizing the query but I get an error that I can't parameterize a tuple. Trying to find a way to do these 2 queries without processing the data inbetween. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the query so that it can be properly parameterized:

```
query = """SELECT element FROM table2 WHERE id IN (%s) """ % ",".join(['%s'] * len(results))
```

This will transform the query to:

```
query = """SELECT element FROM table2 WHERE id IN (%s,%s,%s) """
```

Then you can just pass `query` and `results` to the `execute()` (or appropriate) method so that `results` are properly parameterized.

Comment: thanks, this works. is there any performance downside to doing this?

Comment: @ensnare A performance downside you could encounter would be if you had 1000+ IDs because the query would have `id IN (%s, %s, ... repeated 1000+ times)` which could be large, but that could be solved with batching if it is an issue.